# angular and jquery not loading on aws remote server after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, amazon-ec2

I am using AngularJS, rails and AWS EC2 instance for my web application. 
My website work fine before deployment.but after deployment I got errors like:

> - Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined    jquery.dataTables.min.js:5
> - Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

Comment: Most likely the paths to the Javascript files are incorrect.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I have check all paths. All is correct.but I din't get any solution yet.

Comment: Or order of loading is incorrect. Check browser dev tools network to make sure they are actually loading

Comment: I already checked, all order of loading is correct.

Answer (score 0):

just make the index.html structure like this

> 1.jquery cdn,
>    2.jquery library,
>    3.angular.min.js,
>    4.angular lib

Comment: The problem is happening because of CDN.

Comment: I removed CDN changes.everything works fine.angular resource not loading.